# PHP getdate() outputs only year, and not current

Tags: php, date

I have this php code that I want to output the current year, month and day.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Sweden/Stockholm');
$time_info = getdate();
$day = $time_info['mday'];
$month = $time_info["mon"];
$year = $time_info['year'];
$date = "$year, $month, $day";
```

And the output:

```
2014 10 29
```

But I want it to output

```
year-month-day
```

But when I change the `$date` to `$date = $year."-".$month."-".$day."-";` the output is: `1975`. 
Obviously, this is wrong, so how can I fix it. And a explanation why this occurs would also be great.

**EDIT:**

Ok, so according to @Marc B and @Barry , it did at some point math, and they were right. I don't know why this occurs, but I got it sorted out. Thanks!

Comment: that should work. but note that 1975 is 2014 minus 10 minus 29 - e.g. somewhere you're doing **MATH**, not concatenation.

Comment: Why don't you use something like  *date('Y-m-d', time());*

Comment: Just use `$date = "$year-$month-$day"`. But I agree with Marc B, is `$date` offered to an object that evaluates the value?

Comment: I really don't think you're doing `$date = $year."-".$month."-".$day."-";` I think you're doing `$date = $year-$month-$day;` and it's doing the math to get 1975.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the php [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function?

```
echo date("Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get that if you run this.

```
$time_info = getdate();
echo $time_info->format('Y-m-d');
```

Using PHP `format()` function resolves your problem.
Documentation is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Answer (score 0):

use php date function Use Like this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Sweden/Stockholm');

echo date("Y-m-d");
```